# How to add widget script to Blazor page

Tags: javascript, widget, blazor

I need to add widget script to my Blazor project.

If I'm adding script to _Host.cshtml this widget runs on all project pages.
But I need to run it only on selected pages.

I can't insert

```
    <script src="//code-ya.jivosite.com/widget/kiMhndUDCT" async></script>
```

to .razor component.

How can i do that with JSRuntime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1. Create a Component: [Blazor Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
2. Within that Component, use [JS Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
3. Add this "Widget Blazor Componenet" that you just made to your pages you need.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: how can I call anonimous function using JSInterop? InvokeAsync require JS function name as parameter. But widget script started from !function(){}